# Sort and check IP address sequence

Tags: python, ip, using, sequencing

My requirements are:

1. I have a script which takes care of finding free IPs in a given subnet (old written, works nice).
2. I am automating to create pool of IPs, but has to be in sequence, so can be kind of wrapper for above script

   - Execute the script inside python to know free IPs
   - check whether it can give me 3 IPs in sequence, followed by another sequence of 40 or
   - check whether it can give me 3 IPs in sequence, followed by another sequence of 80
   - I have another script which can register DNS entries for found IPs based on a naming criteria input..

python script possibly to do it like below -

whatever.py -range3,40 -register name (based on basic name, it will create standard names from it. Naming is like below:

```
name-FI-A
name-FI-B 
name-kvm01 through kvm80
```

Hoping to get some help.. I am just beginner on python .. no clue yet..I can give more details if needed.